# How to call Python script from groovy

Tags: python, groovy

I want my python to add something to a txt file and I want to use groovy to activate my python script.

My groovy script:

```
def cmd = "python E:\\mypython\\hello.py"
def proc = cmd.execute()
```

My python script:

```
import os
import sys
f=open("testoutput.txt","a")
f.write("hello")
f.close()
```

I am using an online compiler for groovy. It seems there is no error while running it, but my python script does not work and nothing is added to my txt file. What is going wrong? How should I fix this? After fixing this, my plan is to create a transition button in jira workflow and add my groovy script in the post function section for this transition, so as long as I press the transition button in my issue ticket, it will activate my python script to do something. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, if it's not returning any error that means that it's running the command!

In your python script you are opening the file without any path specifier like this `f=open("testoutput.txt","a")`, so python will use the current directory.

But since the python subprocess is created from the groovy code, then unless you specify it, it will just inherit the working directory of the current groovy process.

Using the same execute command (in groovy) you can check the working directory:

```
["sh", "-c", "pwd"].execute().text
```

Or if you want to make sure your python script is being called just make it print the current directory it is in:

```
import os

print(f"I am in directory: {os.getcwd()}")
```

In the groovy code you can read the output of the process with `.text`

```
"python E:\\mypython\\hello.py".execute().text
```

You can work around this by either providing a directory argument in groovy (see documentation: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html) or by specifying a qualified path in your python script.

As for the second question: Please only post one question per question! This makes everything from answering to googling easier!

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for your scenario, but one could do it with Jython in the following way:

```
groovy.grape.Grape.grab(group:'org.python', module:'jython-standalone', version:'2.7.3')

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter
import org.python.core.*

class AJythonCall {
    static void callJython() throws PyException {
    
    PythonInterpreter jython = new PythonInterpreter()

    println "Hello, Jython"
    jython.exec("import sys")
    jython.exec("print sys")

    jython.set("a", new PyInteger(42))
    jython.exec("print a")
        
    jython.exec("x = 2 + 2")
    PyObject x = jython.get("x")

    println "x: " + x
    println "Bye, Jython"
    }
}
```

Or you can have the script inside your Groovy like this:

```
class AJythonScriptCall {
    static void callJythonScript() throws PyException {
        
    PythonInterpreter jython = new PythonInterpreter()
        
    jython.exec("""
            |num = 1
            |if num >= 0:
            |    if num == 0:
            |        print("Zero")
            |    else:
            |        print("Positive number")
            |else:
            |    print("Negative number")
            """.stripMargin())
    }
}


a = new AJythonCall().callJython()
b = new AJythonScriptCall().callJythonScript()
```

YMMV though, because [Jython 3](https://github.com/jython/jython3) is still in its infancy.